# Is there a way to prime the cache for all pages in Prestashop?

Tags: performance, caching, prestashop

I trying to make my prestashop site faster. My question is: is there a way to get all products pages cached AT ONCE. I already enabled the cache. But if you visit a page for the first time it take too much time to load. Then, the second visit is much faster.

I don't see any feature in the admin page to get this.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a cron task that calls product URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no but you can create a script which will load every product pages on your website.

Put this script at the root of your Prestashop installation `/test.php`. and call it from your browser `www.mywebsite.com/test.php`:

```php
<?php

// The script will not timeout for 10 hours
set_time_limit(36000);

// Set the right path to config.inc.php
include_once (__DIR__ . '/config/config.inc.php');

// Set a default controller to remove unwanted warnings.
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->controller = new FrontController();

// Get all products
$products = Product::getProducts(1, 0, 1000000, 'id_product', 'DESC', false, true, $context);

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    // Load the product page
    $link = $context->link->getProductLink($product['id_product']);
    file_get_contents($link);

    // Print this to screen right away
    print "loaded: " . $link . "<br />";
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    // Stop for 0.2 seconds
    usleep(200000);
}
```

Comment: It works but it takes almost 10 sec to load every link. I have 800 products. It will take more than 2 hours to get it finished.

Comment: Yes it needs to generate the cache for every pages. This is not a process you will do repetitively right? If this answers your question, could you please accept it as the right answer? [How does accepting an answer works?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)